# Add multiline html field is not showing HTML Ribbon tools

Tags: 2010, development

I am trying to add a new column to a contentytpe and type note but with rich text enabled.

It doesnt throw any exceptions:
In the site columns definition it appears as Multiple lines of text with rich text enabled.

However when I place the cursor inside the field, the ribbon is not chaning to show the bold,italic, etc.

the code is as follows:

```
using (SPSite spsite = new SPSite(strurl))
                {
                    using (SPWeb currentWeb = spsite.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                            SPContentType agendaPointsProposedCT = currentWeb.ContentTypes[Meetings.Common.Constants.CONTENTTYPES_AGENDAPOINTPROPOSED_NAME];
                            string reasonReturnedFieldName = currentWeb.Fields.Add(Meetings.Common.Constants.FIELDS_AGENDAPOINTSREASONRETURNED_NAME, SPFieldType.Note, false);
                            SPFieldMultiLineText reasonReturnedField = currentWeb.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(reasonReturnedFieldName) as SPFieldMultiLineText;

                            reasonReturnedField.Group = "$Resources:XXX,Field_XXXColumns_Group";
                            string schemaXmlWithResourceTokens = reasonReturnedField.SchemaXmlWithResourceTokens;
                            string displaynamelocalized = "$Resources:XXX,Field_ReasonReturned_Name";
                            string returnValue;
                            int indexOfAttributeName = schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.IndexOf("DisplayName", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
                            int indexOfAttibuteValueBegin = schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.IndexOf('"', indexOfAttributeName);
                            int indexOfAttributeValueEnd = schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.IndexOf('"', indexOfAttibuteValueBegin + 1);
                            returnValue = schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.Substring(0, indexOfAttibuteValueBegin + 1) + displaynamelocalized + schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.Substring(indexOfAttributeValueEnd);
                            reasonReturnedField.SchemaXml = returnValue;
                            reasonReturnedField.RichText = true;
                            reasonReturnedField.RichTextMode = SPRichTextMode.FullHtml;
                            reasonReturnedField.AllowHyperlink = true;
                            reasonReturnedField.Update(true);

                            agendaPointsProposedCT.AddFieldRefFromContentType(currentWeb, reasonReturnedField, true);
                            MoveFieldInColumnOrderToLastPosition(currentWeb, Meetings.Common.Constants.CONTENTTYPES_AGENDAPOINTPROPOSED_NAME, reasonReturnedField.InternalName);


  public static void AddFieldRefFromContentType(this SPContentType contentType, SPWeb web,SPField field, bool pushChanges)
        {
            SPFieldLink fieldLink = new SPFieldLink(web.AvailableFields.GetField(field.InternalName));
            //Check if the Field reference exists
            if (!contentType.Fields.ContainsField(field.Title))
            {
                contentType.FieldLinks.Add(fieldLink);
                contentType.Update(pushChanges);
            }
            else
            {
                //Do Nothing
            }
        }
```

Comment: I found this, http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010programming/thread/313a3d98-53ca-480d-9841-2ccdbf4a8345, but I am getting the field after adding it, so no sure how to implement the solution here

Comment: I'd be curious to see what the line:contentType.Fields.ContainsField(field.Title)) returns.

Comment: ...because if it returns false your update code never gets hit

Comment: it gets hit, the field is in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to solve it:

Solution I found is here:
http://levalencia.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/add-spfieldmultilinetext-html-field-by-code-wont-show-html-ribbon-tools/